# Opening a new file in TextMate opens the last opened file as well

Tags: applications, text-editor, textmate

Here is a small annoyance that I have with TextMate. When I want to open a new file in TextMate when it's not running it also opens the last opened file. Now for some cases that's just nice of him to do but in most cases I end-up closing the previous file. Maybe this is a simple setup/preference issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not something you can set in the app preferences.

If you want to change this behavior, open Terminal.app and type

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDisableSessionRestore 1
```

This will make Textmate **not** remember the last session.

Change the `1` by `0` if you want the default behavior.

Comment: This doesn't work with Textmate 2...

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is bypassed in Textmate 2 by holding shift when opening Textmate 2.

Picture is from Preferences

[image: From Textmate 2 Preferences Pane]